# How do I activate the emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-emulator, android-constraintlayout

When I make changes to the design screen, I cannot see it in the emulator.my goal is to fix the timers.but whatever change I make on the design screen, I can't see that change in the emulator.The timers in the emulator always look the same.
[image]

here are my codes;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#fffdd0"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.12">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_kalp1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/kalp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_kalp1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_kalp1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_kalp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineH2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_double"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/xx"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_kalp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown2x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_double" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fiftyfifty"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_skip"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_double"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown50"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_countdown2x"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_yariyariya"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/skip"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_satinal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdownNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/tv_countdown50"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_skip" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_pop_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_satinal"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/satinal"
    android:onClick="satinalMain"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH3"
    tools:text="00:30" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_soru"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_countdown" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:shadowColor="#E91E63"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_b"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH4" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_c"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_a" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_d"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_b" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_c"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_infoA"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/info"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gec"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3101578796185185/4912585915"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_reklam"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plus"
    android:onClick="startVideoAd"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_kalp_kazan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:text="İzle Kazan"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:text="SKOR :"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_skor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5"
    />
```

I'm just learning design.I am trying to make responsive design.

Comment: Hello @Ugur, your layout's constraints are improper. You can learn ConstraintsLayout from here : https://constraintlayout.com/basics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this answer will help you. If you have any query please let me know, :).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fffdd0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.98" />
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.12">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineH5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85">
</android.support.constraint.Guideline>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_kalp1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/kalp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_kalp1" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="X"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btn_kalp1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_kalp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineH2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_double"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:background="@drawable/xx"
    android:text="2X"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_kalp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown2x"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btn_double"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/btn_double"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_double" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:text="50"
    android:background="@drawable/fiftyfifty"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_skip"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_double"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown50"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/tv_countdown2x"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/skip"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_satinal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_yariyariya"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdownNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="00:00"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/btn_skip"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/btn_skip"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/tv_countdown2x" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_pop_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_satinal"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/satinal"
    android:onClick="satinalMain"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH2" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_countdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH3"
    tools:text="00:30" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_soru"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_countdown" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:shadowColor="#E91E63"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_b"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH4" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_c"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_a" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btn_d"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_b" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:elegantTextHeight="true"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_c"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_infoA"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/info"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_gec"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineH5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3101578796185185/4912585915"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_reklam"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/plus"
    android:onClick="startVideoAd"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_kalp_kazan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/incee"
    android:text="İzle Kazan"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:text="SKOR :"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_skor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guidelineV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineH5"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```